# Как сохранить SDK данные

Tags: android, android-sdk

Я собираюсь переустановить виндовс. И после, не хотелось бы все SDk обратно скачивать и устанавливать.

Хотелось бы узнать, как все sdk файлы сохранить при переустановке Windows?

Comment: сохраните папку SDK куда-нибудь, после переустановки верните на место

Comment: @pavlofff Не могли бы вы написать развернутый ответ? Как мне кажется, автор подразумевает не только SDK, но и все доп. библиотеки (как минимум стандартные). Было бы здорово найти _универсальное автоматическое решение_.